# Group by unique values while summing / adding other values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, group-by, sum

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
arr = [
  {
    price: 2.0,
    unit: "meter",
    tariff_code: "4901.99",
    amount: 200
   },
   {
    price: 2.0,
    unit: "meter",
    tariff_code: "4901.99",
    amount: 200
   },
   {
    price: 14.0,
    unit: "yards",
    tariff_code: "6006.24",
    amount: 500
   },
   {
    price: 14.0,
    unit: "yards",
    tariff_code: "6006.24",
    amount: 500
  }
]
```

I need to group all of these by tariff_code, while summing the price and amounts that correspond with that tariff code.  So my expected output should be:

```
[
  {
    price: 4.0,
    unit: "meter",
    tariff_code: "4901.99",
    amount: 400
   },
   {
    price: 2.0,
    unit: "yards",
    tariff_code: "6006.24",
    amount: 1000
   }
]
```

`receipt_data[:order_items].group_by { |oi| oi[:tariff_code] }.values`

The `group_by` statement used above will allow me to group by tariff_code but I'm unable to work out a way to sum the other values.  I'm sure there is a slick one-liner way to accomplish this...

Comment: Seems to me like you need to use some iterator like `select`, which filters on unique `tarrif_code` values. If you're trying with each element in an array, the Array methods are what you can perform on that array. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html

Comment: I edited your array because it contained a couple of small errors (`amount:` was `:amount:` in two places). I also assigned a variable `arr` to the array. That allows readers to refer to the variable in answers and comments without having to define it.

Comment: Thanks for that!  Sorry, i was in a rush :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two standard ways of addressing problems of this kind. One, which I've taken, is to use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. The other way is to use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), which I expect someone will soon employ in another answer. I do not believe either approach is preferable in terms of efficiency or readability.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:tariff_code]=>g) do |_,o,n|
    { price: o[:price]+n[:price], unit: o[:unit], amount: o[:amount]+n[:amount] }
  end
end.values
  #=> [{:price=>4.0,  :unit=>"meter", :amount=>400},
  #    {:price=>28.0, :unit=>"yards", :amount=>1000}]
```

Note that the receiver of `values` is seen to be:

```
{"4901.99"=>{:price=>4.0,  :unit=>"meter", :amount=>400},
{"6006.24"=>{:price=>28.0, :unit=>"yards", :amount=>1000}}
```

Answer (score 2):

More verbose:

```
grouped_items = arr.group_by { |oi| oi[:tariff_code] }
result = grouped_items.map do |tariff_code, code_items|
  price, amount = code_items.reduce([0, 0]) do |(price, amount), ci|
    [price + ci[:price], amount + ci[:amount]]
  end
  {
    price:       price,
    unit:        code_items.first[:unit],
    tariff_code: tariff_code,
    amount:      amount
  }
end
#[
#  {:price=>4.0, :unit=>"meter", :tariff_code=>"4901.99", :amount=>400}
#  {:price=>28.0, :unit=>"yards", :tariff_code=>"6006.24", :amount=>1000}
#]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the fun, the answer which uses `group_by` as @cary said, and mostly copying Pavel's answer. This is very bad performancewise and **use only if the array is small** . Also it uses `sum` which is available only in Rails. (can be replaced by `.map { |item| item[:price] }.reduce(:+)` in pure ruby)

```rb
arr.group_by { |a| a[:tariff_code] }.map do |tariff_code, items|
  {
    price: items.sum { |item| item[:price] },
    unit: items.first[:unit],
    tariff_code: tariff_code,
    amount: items.sum { |item| item[:amount] }
  }
end
```

This would have been even smaller if it was an array of objects (ActiveRecord objects maybe) with methods instead of hashes.

```rb
arr.group_by(&:tariff_code).map do |tariff_code, items|
  {
    price: items.sum(&:price]),
    unit: items.first[:unit],
    tariff_code: tariff_code,
    amount: items.sum(&:amount)
  }
end
```

Comment: Nice and clean!

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach, but its easy to add new keys for summing and to change a group key. Not sure about efficiency, but 500_000 times Benchmark of `arr.map` here looks good

```
#<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007fad0911b418 @label="", @real=1.480799000000843, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0017340000000000133, @utime=1.4783359999999999, @total=1.48007>
```

```
summ_keys = %i[price amount]
grouping_key = :tariff_code
result = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = {} }
arr.map do |h|
  cumulative = result[h[grouping_key]]
  h.each do |k, v|
    case k
    when *summ_keys
      cumulative[k] = (cumulative[k] || 0) + h[k]
    else
      cumulative[k] = v
    end
  end
end
p result.values

# [{:price=>4.0, :unit=>"meter", :tariff_code=>"4901.99", :amount=>400},
#  {:price=>28.0, :unit=>"yards", :tariff_code=>"6006.24", :amount=>1000}]
```